# go tests: clean up after panic

Tags: testing, go

Suppose that I set up a Docker container with a DB for my tests, and I do that in [testing.TestMain](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main) because I want this to be done once and globally. I write a `defer` statement in this `testing.Main()` that does the cleanup (namely, removes the DB container).

Now, suppose that something goes wrong and my tests panic. [This issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13149) tells me that I can not write custom `recover` code to ensure that the container is removed. This is true: `testing.M.Run()` does its own `recover()` call, and it looks like there's no way to override its behaviour.

The question is: what should I do to make sure that my cleanup code is executed no matter what?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Go and especially testing in Go, `t.Cleanup` from std "testing" might be helpful, as I understand it so far it should always get called. Please correct me if I'm wrong! More here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61609670/3484824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the issue you linked to:

> The panic could come from a goroutine started by a test and the
>   testing package can't add a defer to those goroutines to catch the
>   panic.
>
> Aadditionally, some panics are impossible to recover, e.g. out of
>   menory or runtime memory corruption.

In short, you *cannot make sure* that any code will be executed in all circumstances.

If your cleanup is non-critical, you can do it before & after (i.e. at the start of your tests, check if your container already exists and destroy it before creating a new one, then make a best effort to destroy it at the end). If your cleanup is critical, then wrap your `go test` call with something (e.g. a shell script or makefile) and make the wrapper responsible for the setup & teardown of external dependencies.