# What is useful for t.Cleanup?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, go1.14

## Questions

I would like to know the use case of `t.Cleanup` introduced in Go1.14. What is the convenience of t.Cleanup as compared to using defer?

https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Cleanup.

- Sample

For example, let's say we create a temporary directory, and when we test it, we want to delete the temporary directory we created.

`t.Cleanup` can be used to write a test as follows, but it also works as `defer os.RemoveAll(tempDir)`.

```golang
package mypkg

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestDirwalk(t *testing.T) {
    tempDir, err := ioutil.TempDir(".", "temp")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("create tempDir: %v", err)
    }
    t.Cleanup(func() { os.RemoveAll(tempDir) })

    // something...
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Cleanup functions are also called if your test panics, so in your case both would work.

The advantage of using [`T.Cleanup()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Cleanup) becomes clear if your test calls other functions, passing `testing.T` along. Obviously using `defer` in those functions would be executed before those functions return, but if you register cleanup functions using `T.Cleanup()`, then they will be called only at the end of your test.

Think of `T.Cleanup()` as an "improved" and extended version of `defer`. It also documents that the passed functions are for cleanup purposes.

Comment: _Obviously using defer in those functions would be executed before those functions return, but if you register cleanup functions using T.Cleanup(), then they will be called only at the end of your test._


I finally got it. Thanks.

Comment: Inside tests also `defer` is called if your test panics. `t.Cleanup()` is useful because you can pass it around to helpers and have them specify their own cleanup.

Answer (score 15):

`t.Cleanup` is useful for cleaning up resources allocated by a helper function when the test does not care about the resource itself.

#### Example

Consider testing a service layer. The service uses a `*sql.DB` but does not create it itself.

```
package testutils

import (
  "testing"

  "my/db"
  "my/domain"
)

func NewTestSubject(t *testing.T) *domain.Service {
  t.Helper()  
  sqldb := newDatabase(t)
  s, _ := domain.NewService(sqldb)
  return s
}

func newDatabase(t *testing.T) *sql.DB {
  t.Helper()
  d, _ := db.Create()
  t.Cleanup(func() {
    d.Close()
  })
}
```

Without `t.Cleanup` `newTestSubject` would have to return `(*domain.Service, *sql.DB)`, leaking details about `domain.Service`'s construction.

Comment: t.Cleanup certainly turns out to be useful for handling resources within the Helper function. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to revive this old question. Just wondering, would you consider it more idiomatic to call `t.Cleanup(d.Close)` or to use the extra function as you've done here?

Comment: I'd prefer `t.Cleanup(d.Close)` in this case. However, I think the example is more approachable for newcomers as it is.

Answer (score 8):

Besides what others have pointed out, `t.Cleanup()` is also useful when dealing with parallel subtests, where the cleanup should only run after all subtests have completed. Consider

```golang
func TestSomething(t *testing.T){
   setup()
   defer cleanup()
   t.Run("parallel subtest 1", func(t *testing.T){
      t.Parallel()
      (...)
   })
   t.Run("parallel subtest 2", func(t *testing.T){
      t.Parallel()
      (...)
   })
}
```

which doesn't work because the test function will return while the the subtests are still running, causing the resources required by the subtests to get wiped out by `defer cleanup()`.

Before `t.Cleanup()` a way to solve this was to wrap the subtests on another test

```golang
func TestSomething(t *testing.T){
   setup()
   defer cleanup()
   t.Run("parallel tests", func(t *testing.T){
      t.Run("subtest 1", func(t *testing.T){
         t.Parallel()
         (...)
      })
      t.Run("subtest 2", func(t *testing.T){
         t.Parallel()
         (...)
      })
   })
}
```

which looks ok, but with `t.Cleanup()` it gets way better

```golang
func TestSomething(t *testing.T){
   setup()
   t.Cleanup(cleanup)
   t.Run("parallel subtest 1", func(t *testing.T){
      t.Parallel()
      (...)
   })
   t.Run("parallel subtest 2", func(t *testing.T){
      t.Parallel()
      (...)
   })
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the most important answer to read. That's a really hard bug to find, and an important one to avoid. FYI for others, you can use `goerr113` as an automated linter to find tests that use `defer` instead of `t.Cleanup`.